# Google Auth - should you send the ID token to the FE, or create a new JWT?

Tags: google, jwt

I'm trying to understand what the best practice is here.

When a user signs in with Google, they then send you an 'id_token' which contains a bunch of information about the user, and the token generally.

This is the example Google provides:

```
{
 // These six fields are included in all Google ID Tokens.
 "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
 "sub": "110169484474386276334",
 "azp": "1008719970978-hb24n2dstb40o45d4feuo2ukqmcc6381.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "aud": "1008719970978-hb24n2dstb40o45d4feuo2ukqmcc6381.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "iat": "1433978353",
 "exp": "1433981953",

 // These seven fields are only included when the user has granted the "profile" and
 // "email" OAuth scopes to the application.
 "email": "testuser@gmail.com",
 "email_verified": "true",
 "name" : "Test User",
 "picture": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-kYgzyAWpZzJ/ABCDEFGHI/AAAJKLMNOP/tIXL9Ir44LE/s99-c/photo.jpg",
 "given_name": "Test",
 "family_name": "User",
 "locale": "en"
}
```

My question is, once you have authenticated the 'id_token' sent by Google - should I use this token for a session, or can I replace it with my own JWT which only contains the information that I need it to?

My biggest concern is relating to the expiry date here. If I create my own JWT, then unless I store the expiry date provided by the Google token, then they may get misaligned. On top of that, if a user ends the session with Google (i.e. unlinks their Google account with my app), then the token won't be automatically destroyed like I imagine it would with the Google id_token.

However, I'd be keen not to always have to rely upon Google's servers to validate a user. It just feels cleaner to utilise my own JWT, and it means I can control what's stored in the token itself.

Hope the above makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Using raw ID token as is has its benefits. You don't have to rely on Google to validate the user. Just get the keys from JWKS endpoint and verify it on start of every user session.

1. ID token even if it is expired can be still used for [RP-Initiated Logout](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-rpinitiated-1_0.html) that revokes all tokens issued for the user by the Identity Provider (IdP).
2. ID token if not expired can be shared with your other services.

If the user unlinks the app from its Google account, it is recommended to implement [Backchannel Logout](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-backchannel-1_0.html) to handle session revocation. The IdP will send you the backchannel logout request to your registered **Backchannel endpoint**. Upon receiving the request, you are supposed to purge the server side session of the user and also clear all session cookies if the user is online or will be online.

Using your own custom JWT to wrap ID token limits delegation of authority on the session management. You will have to implement your own token management to revoke, refresh and reissue JWT when needed. You will also have to advertise your public key if you share that JWT with your other services.

You can control what information should be added to the ID token by using scopes.